# VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

```
ubuntu 16.04 LTS
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
$ virtualbox
VirtualBox: supR3HardenedMainGetTrustedMain: dlopen("/usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox.so",) failed: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5: undefined symbol: _ZN6QDebug9putStringEPK5QCharm
```

virtualbox is not run. What's wrong and how can i solve this?

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21  5월 13  2017 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5 -> libQt5OpenGL.so.5.5.1


$ apt-cache policy libqt5opengl5
libqt5opengl5:
설치: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5
후보: 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5
버전 테이블:
*** 5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7.5 500
        500 http://ftp.daum.net/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    5.5.1+dfsg-16ubuntu7 500
        500 http://ftp.daum.net/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the outputs of `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5` and `apt-cache policy libqt5opengl5`

Comment: @steeldriver Okay

Comment: @steeldriver so, waht's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know - I'd hoped there would be something obviously incorrect (such as a 3rd party library version) but that does not appear to be the case

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall *libqt5opengl5*, *libqt5core5a* and *libdouble-conversion1*. This will remove *virtualbox-qt*, which also must be reinstalled. In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt remove libqt5opengl5 libqt5core5a libdouble-conversion1
sudo apt install libqt5opengl5 libqt5core5a libdouble-conversion1 virtualbox-qt
```

libQt5OpenGL.so.5
Run `ldd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5OpenGL.so.5` to see if there are other missing dependencies. If there are, try finding the corresponding package names with `dpkg -S <file-name(s)>` and reinstall them.

Answer (score 0):

DO NOT INSTALL USING `APT INSTALL` THE VIRTUALBOX!

I solved this problem a few weeks before. If you install the `Virtualbox` using `apt install` and got the same problem, remove the `Virtualbox`. I guess `apt install virtualbox` has some problem by dependencies. After then download and install `.deb` file at [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads).